# Strange T-SQL if statement behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL if statement:

```
if @changeType = 'ChangeFrom'
 begin
  print 'yep'
 end
else
 begin
  print 'nope'
 end
```

If `@changeType = 'ChangeFrom'` I get yep.
If `@changeType = 'ChangeTo'` I get nope.
If `@changeType ='ChangeFromfsjkfh'` I get yep!  Whats going on there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What length have you declared the @ChangeType variable as - it looks like it's getting truncated?

Comment: Ah @Paddy I think you've hit the nail on the head there!  Its a char(10) which would explain why this is happening